# Batch - Copy - Si se abre ventana con error darle a aceptar de forma automática con un .bat

Tags: shell, batch, powershell

Tengo un error en los .bat automáticos, que cuando encuentra un archivo existente, en uno de los casos se abre una ventana de error "Error, ya existe un archivo con el mismo nombre".
/Y copia y sobreescribe, pero ¿Cómo darle a "aceptar" a cualquier ventana emergente de forma automática?

Código copiar.bat:

```
@echo off
copy "x:\sofrel\*.csv" "d:\" /Y
```

(Este código con la /Y fuerza la copia aunque encuentre archivo con el mismo nombre). Pero si se abre una ventana de error, ¿Cómo darle a aceptar de forma automática?

Un saludo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te recomiendo utilizar `ROBOCOPY` en lugar de `COPY`, yo lo utilizo para mis backups. Es un comando mucho más potente con ciertas ventajas:

- Tolera las interrupciones en la copia de archivos ya sea por cortes
  de energía o en la conexión.
- Realiza reintentos automáticos si no se puede acceder a un archivo.
- Permite copiar grandes cantidades de archivos, imposible con XCOPY.
- Muestra indicador de progreso.
- Permite copiado multihilo.
- Copia correctamente toda la información como propiedades, atributos, datos del propietario, fechas, etc además mantiene inalterables los permisos del archivo.

Dicho esto, para utilizar `robocopy` tienes los siguientes comandos:

```
ROBOCOPY ORIGEN DESTINO /E
```

Permite copiar de forma recursiva carpetas con subdirectorios aunque estén vacíos.

```
ROBOCOPY ORIGEN DESTINO /S
```

Copia de forma recursiva carpetas con subdirectorios pero no los vacios

```
ROBOCOPY ORIGEN DESTINO /MIR
```

MIR modo espejo, Copia de forma recursiva pero al terminar se eliminan los archivos en el destino que ya no existen en el origen.

Es posible indicar archivos específicos para ser copiados usando asteriscos de la siguiente forma:

```
ROBOCOPY ORIGEN DESTINO *.doc /E
```

En este caso solo se copiarán documentos de extensión de archivo .DOC, si esta opción no es utilizada se emplea de forma predeterminada *.* o sea se copian todos los archivos encontrados.

**Opciones que permite el comando ROBOCOPY**

```
/R:n
```

Numero de reintentos en caso de algún error.

```
/W:n
```

Tiempo de espera entre reintentos.

```
/MT:n
```

Realiza copias multiproceso, n especifica el número de hilos, el valor predeterminado es 8, n debe estar comprendido entre 1 y 128.

```
/MOV
```

Mueve archivos y los elimina del origen después de ser copiados.

```
/MOVE
```

Mueve archivos y carpetas y los elimina del origen después de ser copiados.

```
/V
```

Mostrar información detallada durante la copia.

```
/L
```

Hace una simulación, solo mostrar no copia.

```
/FP
```

Incluir ruta de acceso completa de los archivos en el resultado.

```
/NJH
```

No muestra el encabezado en la consola.

```
/NJS
```

No muestra el resumen final.

```
/Z
```

Copia archivos en modo reiniciable. Escribirá un registro en el archivo incompleto en caso de que la operación se vea interrumpida, para que en otra ejecución de Robocopy pueda continuarse por donde se dejó.

```
/MAX:n
```

Tamaño máximo de archivo, no se copian archivos mayores que el valor de n expresado en bytes.

```
/MIN:n
```

Tamaño mínimo de archivo, no se copian archivos menores que el valor de n expresado en bytes.

```
/MAXAGE:n
```

Antigüedad máxima de archivo, no se copian archivos mayores que el valor de n en días, puede usarse también fecha.

```
/MINAGE:n
```

Antigüedad mínima de archivo no se copian archivos menores que el valor de n en días, puede usarse también fecha.

```
/RH:hhmm-hhmm
```

Horas de ejecución, intervalo de horas en formato de 24 horas en que se debe iniciar la copia.

```
/LOG:log.txt
```

Permite guardar un informe con los datos de la copia efectuada en un archivo de texto.

*Toda la información ha sido extraida de [aqui](https://norfipc.com/comandos/como-usar-comando-robocopy-ejemplos.html)*

Comment: Muchas gracias por dar una respuesta tan detallada Miguel.